# Qual é a essência para se modelar um sistema?

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Devida a minha ociosidade no estágio e falta de conhecimento para atuar em projetos mesmo de médio porte estou buscando uma missão que me faça aumentar os conhecimentos tanto em PHP (principalmente) como em banco de dados (no caso MySQL), mas junto a isso agregando conhecimento também em OO, Js, HTML5/CSS (bootstrap), MVC, ZendFramework e planejamento de sistemas em si.

Bem, estou pensando em desenvolver um portal de notícias como por exemplo http://canaltech.com.br/ mas devido a falta de conhecimento não sei bem como poderia começar de forma correta (quero sempre usar boas práticas) de se começar a desenvolver um projeto assim. Acredito que vontade é uma delas, depois vem a necessidade, tudo bem, mas e a parte de estrutura mesmo, quais seriam as dicas recomendadas para nisso?

ps: Nem sei se esse tipo de pergunta é válida aqui.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Como você irá reparar pela quantidade de downvotes (tem gente que tem um prazer quase orgásmico em dar votos negativos), não é uma questão que cabe aqui no SOPT. Você precisa vir com dúvidas mais concretas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comece primeiramente escrevendo 3 historias.

1 - Historia detalhada de como você deseja o portal.

2 - Historia de como as pessoas vão usar o portal

3 - Historia de como os responsáveis vão atualizar o portal

Com essas 3 historias prontas, identifique os **substantivos** e as **ações**.

Os substantivos provavelmente serão suas tabelas do banco e as ações serão as ligações entre cada uma delas.

Depois que tiver isso tudo elencado, priorize quais desses substantivos/tabelas são principais para o seu projeto e comece o desenvolvimento por elas.